# Backspace calculator in jquery

Tags: jquery

So I am making a calculator using HTML,CSS,JQUERY,Bootstrap. The input of calculator will be clicked, not typed. The #C is to erase all, and the #del is to erase one number only (like backspace). The #C works fine, but the #del is not. My #del function worked the same as #C, it erased everything. Anyone know why? Thanks!

```
$('#C').click(function()
{
    $('#answer').val('');
    $('#operation').val('');
    $('#operation').removeClass('activeAnswer');
    $('#equals').attr('onclick','');
});

$('#del').click(function()
{
    $('#answer').val('');
    $('#operation').val($('#operation').val().slice(0, $('#operation').val().length-1));
    $('#operation').removeClass('activeAnswer');
    $('#equals').attr('onclick','');
});
```

Comment: It's odd that you are combining jQuery click listeners with the `onclick` attribute. Could you include more code so we can see the issue ourselves?

Comment: I think slice is the wrong command here. You should use substring